# Fetching large amount of data with loop or recursion with progress percentage in React / React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, memory-leaks

Hi am writing a react native app from android version **4.4.4** to **latest**. I have a situation where need to download **millions** of records and then store to local database ([using watermelon DB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB)). I am paginating records and getting data with xhr request (10000 in one shot).

Fetching and storing both are async operation. i can do this using loop or recursion.

**Recursion Snippet:**

```
dataFetch = async () => {
    if (maxPages && page > maxPages) {
      return true;
    }
    const { data } = await axios.get(API_GET_RECORDS, {
      params: {
        page,
        per_page: 10000,
      },
    });
    if (data.data && data.data.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    await addIntoDatabase(this.props.database, data.data);
    if ((maxPages || data.max_pages) && page) {
      this.setState({
        message: `Loading ${Number.parseFloat(
          (page * 100) / (maxPages || data.max_pages),
        )}%`,
      });
      // console.log((page * 100) / (maxPages || data.max_pages));
    }
    return this.dataFetch(page + 1, data.max_pages);
  };
```

**Loop Snippet**

```
dataFetch = async () => {
    let page = 1;
    let maxPages;
    do {
      const { data } = await axios.get(API_GET_RECORDS, {
        params: {
          page,
          per_page: 10000,
        },
      });
      await addIntoDatabase(this.props.database, data.data);
      if (data.max_pages && page) {
        this.setState({
          message: `Loading ${Math.round((page * 100) / data.max_pages)}%`,
        });
      }
      page += 1;
      maxPages = data.max_pages;
    } while (page < maxPages);
  };
```

**Function calling**

```
downloadMyDataAndDoOtherTask = () => {
 // ... some task
 dataFetch(); // you should get all the data then start executing next line
 // ... some other task depends on this task;
}
```

> 1. What is best approach loop or recursion in this kind of situation ?
> 2. In react when we do setState in any kind of loops or recursion that time it won't update immediately ([Batch update concept](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)). if i want to show some progress percentage in this kind of case how can i show. Because react won't update in all the iterations so that progress will be behind then actual progress.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Both ways(loop and recursion) after downloading around 2-3 lacks of data app get's crashed.

Comment: Since you want all your records to be stored in local db, have you thought about exporting the database table in a file and downloading that file from client app. and read that file and loop on it, and store records into db. you can show progress on the downloading of file.

Comment: That is also good idea. i thought of that as well but time is less and i don't have much experience with file handling with react native i thought not to touch now.
But thanks for suggestion will be implementing in future but you do have any solution for set state for now ?

Comment: Also File is not efficient for backend because for each user that data differs so on each api call server has to generate file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive method and use setState callback for next iteration:

```
dataFetch = async () => {
  // ...
  this.setState({
    message: `Loading ${Number.parseFloat(
      (page * 100) / (maxPages || data.max_pages),
    )}%`,
  }, () => {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.dataFetch(page + 1, data.max_pages);
    });
  });
};
```

In this way, it will first set your progress in state and continue fetching after state is updated.

Comment: I've already thought of this but code wont wait for this function call to finish all data, and just after first iteration other part will start executing. i'll update snippet wait.

Comment: Still this solution won't work as callback function will get called after after updating state object not render.

Comment: @ShubhanuSharma try this with `InteractionManager`. Updated code snippet.

Comment: this also will give same response only because this will be used for animation and interactions it wont wait for render to finish.